# as.factor not working to convert numerical variable to categorical variable

Tags: r

I am trying to convert some numerical variables to categorical variables using as.factor but is not working. Since I am a relatively new R user I am not sure about my code. When I try to run a regression model the results also presented numerical variables. Does anyone have any suggestions?

````
as.factor(data$race_fup)
is.factor(data$sex)
str(data)


 $ sex             : num [1:812] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ race_fup        : num [1:812] 1 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ education_degree: num [1:812] 2 1 3 4 2 0 1 4 6 7 ...

GLM.1 <- glm(intubation ~ sex + education_degree + race_fup, family = binomial(logit) , data=data)```
Warning message:
glm.fit: probabilidades ajustadas numericamente 0 ou 1 ocorreu 
summary(GLM.1)

Call:
`glm(formula = intubation ~ sex + education_degree + race_fup, 
    family = binomial(logit), data = data)`
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0701  -1.0002  -0.9472   1.3353   1.5188  

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      -2.577e-01  1.514e-01  -1.702   0.0888
sex              -3.769e-02  1.455e-01  -0.259   0.7956
education_degree -6.837e-02  3.877e-02  -1.764   0.0778
race_fup         -6.052e-05  5.799e-04  -0.104   0.9169
                  
(Intercept)      .
sex               
education_degree .
race_fup          
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1074.1  on 806  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1069.9  on 803  degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 1077.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
````

Comment: You need to assign the converted value to the same object `data$race_fup <- as.factor(data$race_fup)`

Comment: Thank you, this probably some beginner mistake. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

There are some functions which changes in place i.e. if we use `:=` in data.table, it modifies the original object or the `set` functions i.e. `setDT` - converts the original object from data.frame to data.table

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c("race_fup", "sex")
setDT(data)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = nm1]
```

---

Or another option is compound assignment operator (`%<>%`) from `magrittr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
data %<>%
     mutate(across(c(race_fup, sex), as.factor))
```

whereas if we use the `%>%`, it wont change the original object unless we assign (`<-` (at the beginning)

```
data <- data %>%
       mutate(across(c(race_fup, sex), as.factor))
```

or `->` (at the end))

```
data %>%
       mutate(across(c(race_fup, sex), as.factor)) -> data
```

---

In `base R`, without doing any assignment, the original object stays the same

```
data[c('race_fup', 'sex')] <- lapply(data[c('race_fup', 'sex')], as.factor)
```

NOTE: If there are multiple columns, we could use either one of the methods